# AUNetSend to Linux

Tags: linux, macos, raspberry-pi

Got a mac laptop, and looking to stream live audio to a linux box.

I very much like the AUNetSend module in AU Lab on the mac, and would like to stream the audio using this to a linux machine. Is this possible?

I've tried connecting through VLC and there seems to be some sort of HTTP server going on there but not really sure...

Any ideas if it is possible, how I could do it, or any other ways for me to send live audio from a microphone input (soundflower) on a mac to a linux box with **very low latency**?

Comment: I want to know this too. I am also amazed that google indexed a question 3 hours old. Have you looked into Jack? I seriously was asking this question of myself just a few hours ago.